# Material Design theme in Android app - menu item icon isn't inheriting from the theme

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, material-design, android-theme

I'm new to Android development so sorry if this is a dumb question but Google and past SO questions aren't helping.

I want to use a dark theme for my app, so I've set my theme as:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents">
```

I have a toolbar which contains a menu with 2 items. The menu is defined as:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.mycompany.myapp.MainActivity">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_contacts"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_contacts_24"
        android:title="@string/action_contacts"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

The issue I have is that, while the toolbar is correctly using the dark theme, the first menu item (`@+id/action_open_contacts`) is setting the icon color to black, so it can barely be seen. The overflow menu is working correctly though and shows a white menu icon.

Why isn't the contacts icon displaying as white? Shouldn't this be inherited from the app's theme just like the menu icon?

Answer (score -1):

You can possible to wrap it by .

Add this file into drawable folder - **settings_icon.xml**:

```
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_contacts_24"
    android:tint="@color/colorBlack"/>
```

Create colorBlack or put the hexadecimal color like #000000.

Then use your drawable for menu item:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.mycompany.myapp.MainActivity">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_contacts"
        android:icon="@drawable/settings_icon"
        android:title="@string/action_contacts"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

I hope It help you!

Comment: Won't that just change the icon color to black though?

Comment: It just tint black the icon not the original icon. It will help you when you have a color icon and you just want to take other color. I hope it help you!